# How can i use scope's variable in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive

I want to get a scope's variable in directive as a javascript variable.
Here is my code:

```
app.controller("Home", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    ...
    $scope.nb_msg = data.length;
    ...
}]);

app.directive("myDiv", function() {
    // Here, i want to get $scope.nb_msg
    var nb_msg = ???;
    var result = [];
    // do something with nb_msg to get result
    var template = "";
    ...
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        template += "<span>" + result[i] + "</span>";
    }
    ...

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: template
    };
});
```

How can i do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access scope in your link function:

```
app.directive("myDiv", function() {    
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<span ng-repeat="i in result">{{i}}</span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {

             // Here, i want to get $scope.nb_msg
             var nb_msg = scope.nb_msg;
             scope.result = [];
             for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
                 scope.result.push(i);
             }


        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the template variable is inside link function? Do u think i can use it for setting template of this directive? Or i must return it in the link function? Sorry i m very new in angularjs.

Comment: Templates are normally a child of the directive element. Angular will automatically compile and link the template and add it as a child of your directive element. It is possible to dynamically compile and link a fragment of HTML, but if you can use the templating mechanism of Angular, you should.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much. I only have one problem. I want to add a css block in directive because i can't define it before, it s based on the variable nb_msg like that: @keyframes myAnimation, the percentages depend on nb_msg. For ex: if nb_msg = 2, it must be 0%, 50%, 100%; nb_msg=3; 0% 30% 50% 70% 100%. It s why i need to write template above that help me to add a css block. So can i create this css block in directive? And how can i do that? Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

if your directive doesn't create an isolated scope the variables will be available inside the directives controller, compile and link functions.

if your directive does create an isolated scope you can't, not like that, directives are not aware of outide controllers so they can't access controllers variables, you do have other choices

1st -- use the controller variable as an attribute value for the directive and linked it using '=' in your scope if you want to provide 2 way binding;

2nd -- put the variables to share inside a service and inject it into both the controller and the directive.

3rd --(less recommended) use scope.$parent to access the controllers scope, this approach always assumes that your directive will always be contained inside that controller.

Note. in any case you will have the variables available in the directives definition function